# Show that $R_{\mu} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\lambda - \mu)^n R_{\lambda}^{n+1}$

Tags: operator-theory

## Question

Let $A: L \rightarrow L$ be a closed linear operator on $L$, show that if $\lambda$ is in the resolvent set of $A$ and $|\lambda - \mu| < \|R_{\lambda}\|^{-1}$, show that:
$$
R_{\mu} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\lambda - \mu)^n R_{\lambda}^{n+1}.
$$

This ought to be shown using the identities: $R_{\lambda} R_{\mu} = R_{\mu} R_{\lambda} = (\lambda - \mu)^{-1} (R_{\mu} - R_{\lambda})$.

## Origin of the question

I am reading through the book [Kurtz and Ethier](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-047176986X.html) which is quite painful and I couldn't work this equation out.

Comment: Why don't you say what $L$ is and how $R_\mu$ is defined? You cannot show this with the resolvent identity because a priori you don't know whether $R_\mu$ exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
(A-\mu)(A-\lambda)^{-1} = ((A-\lambda)+(\lambda-\mu))(A-\lambda)^{-1} = I + (\lambda-\mu)(A-\lambda)^{-1}.
$$
So,
$$
A-\mu = \left[I + (\lambda-\mu)(A-\lambda)^{-1}\right](A-\lambda).
$$
By your requirement that $|\lambda-\mu| < \|(A-\lambda)^{-1}\|^{-1}$, the bounded operator $I + (\lambda-\mu)(A-\lambda)^{-1}$ is invertible. Thus, $A-\mu$ must be invertible. Its inverse is
$$
R_\mu = R_\lambda\left[I - (\mu - \lambda)R_\lambda\right]^{-1} = R_\lambda\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\mu - \lambda)^kR_\lambda^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(\mu - \lambda)^kR_\lambda^{k+1}.
$$

Comment: How does this show the claimed equality?

Comment: I do understand what you say and it is indeed also useful!

Comment: I edited for the equality.

Comment: Ok that part was quite obvious nice thanks will probably post many more questions of this type in the near future

Comment: I will maybe help you next time if you upvote my answer. ;-)

Comment: I did. Someone downvoted it, I have no idea why as you answered my question perfectly

Comment: Oh, ok. Sorry then. Cu.